# Display a view inside a field collection with eva

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'm trying to display a view inside a field collection via [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva). I've created the view which accepts the nid of the containing content type as the context argument and all is good in that the view shows correctly when the nid is passed in, however I think the problem is that a field collection is stored as a separate piece of content, so the nid that is supplied when viewing is not that of the containing content type.

The view returns nothing when inserted into the field collection.

Is there a specific way to get the containing content-type nid into the view via the field collection? I've looked in the tokens section for the argument input in the eva view, but nothing specifically for the containing nid, only the specific field collection nid.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking outside the box a bit, the answer lies in setting the contextual filter to accept the "field collection item" id using the appropriate relationship (not the field collection item entity).